# Amazon AWS CLI delete ApiGateway, possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, api-gateway

Is there a way to Delete a Amazon API Gateway from the aws cli ?

I created a bunch of gateways, and it takes a while to remove them from the GUI. Is there a way to do it from aws cli

Couldn't find any examples anywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can delete the APIs using AWS CLI. To delete a Rest API using CLI, we need the rest API id. To get that, run the `get-rest-apis` CLI and then delete it.

Here's a script to delete all the rest APIs:

```
for rest_api_id in $(aws apigateway get-rest-apis --region us-east-1 --query 'items[*].id' --output text); do aws apigateway delete-rest-api --region us-east-1 --rest-api-id $rest_api_id ; done
```

Of course this will delete all the APIs. To delete selectively, run the commands separately.

References:

- Get Rest APIs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-rest-apis.html
- Delete Rest API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/delete-rest-api.html

Answer (score 0):

for rest_api_id in $(aws apigateway get-rest-apis --region eu-central-1 --query 'items[*].id' --output text); do aws apigateway delete-rest-api --region eu-central-1 --rest-api-id $rest_api_id; sleep 10; done

^
In case you run into rate limiting issues like I did.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).